# turn numbers in string into individual byte objects java

Tags: java

I want to turn the string "12345" into an array of byte objects of 1 2 3 4 and 5.

```
  byte[] n1 = new byte[num.length()];
  for (int i = 0; i< num.length(); i++) {
     n1[i] = (byte)num.charAt(i);
  }
```

it is turning the numbers into ascii values (12345 becomes 49 50 51 52 53)
and i do not want that. any suggestions?

Comment: just subtract 48, n1[i] = ((byte)num.charAt(i)) - 48;

Comment: Are you sure you *need* to use a `byte` array? They're clunky to work with, and much slower than working with the native word size (`int`/`long`)

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the offset of `'0'`

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "12345";

        byte[] digits = new byte[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++) {
            digits[i] = (byte) (s.charAt(i) - '0');
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(digits)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    }
}
```